# Как воспользоваться сервис-провайдером или фасадом с передачей параметра?

Tags: php, laravel

Мне нужно получить нужный экземпляр класса по передаваемому параметру. Но текущая реализация мне кажется громоздкой и какой-то неправильной. Можно ли это сделать как-то короче через сервис-провайдер либо фасад?

Приведу пример текущей реализации:

```
<?php

namespace App\Core\Domain\Constants;

use App\Core\Domain\NotificationSending\Sms\Providers\GmsViberSms;
use App\Core\Domain\NotificationSending\Sms\Providers\SerwerSms\SerwerSmsProvider;

class OrderChatMessageType
{
    public const VIBER = 1;
    public const SERWERSMS = 2;

    public const PROVIDERS = [
        self::VIBER => GmsViberSms::class,
        self::SERWERSMS => SerwerSmsProvider::class
    ];

    // Достаем нужный класс
    private static function get_class_provider(int $service_type): ?string
    {
        return self::PROVIDERS[$service_type] ?? null;
    }

    // Достаем экземпляр класса
    public static function get_provider(int $service_type)
    {
        return resolve(self::get_class_provider($service_type));
    }
}
```

И собственно получение экзепляра:

```
$service_provider = OrderChatMessageType::get_provider($service_type);
```

(Каждый из этих провайдеров имплеменрирует единый интерфейс)

Comment: а в сервис контейнере (или где оно там) вы не можете настроить привязку с параметрами, что бы просто вызывать `resolve(IProviderInterface, $service_type)` ?

Comment: Я пробовал, но в таком случае тоде некрасиво выглядит. `resolve` вторым параметром принимает массив аргументов. Получится `resolve(IProviderInterface, [$service_type])` или `resolve(IProviderInterface, ["service_type" => $service_type])`. Очень громоздко

Answer (score 1):

По сути Ваш код не плох и имеет место быть. Почему в данном случае уменьшить код достаточно сложно. Проблема заключается в том, что в передаёте цифровые ключи (предположу что с фронта) и в этот момент Вам придётся всё равно проверять типы и получать провайдер. То есть переделывая код на контейнеры вы всё равно не уменьшите код особо, а просто разнесёте по файлам. НО! есть мега крутой способ как это всё таки можно сделать =) Задаче связать число с классом.

Если что это всё мои фантазии, но они имеют место быть и будут работать). Далее решать уже Вам.

Мы удаляем весь код из `OrderChatMessageType` кроме первых двух констант.
Либо вообще удаляете класс и создаёте `enum` если у вас php 8

Далее в сервис провайдере в методе `register` или `boot` делаем следующее:

```
$this->app->bind(OrderChatMessageType::VIBER, GmsViberSms::class);
$this->app->bind(OrderChatMessageType::SERWERSMS, SerwerSmsProvider::class);
```

И по сути всё.

Далее `resolve(1)`  или `resolve(OrderChatMessageType::VIBER)` будет возвращать ваш класс то есть метод `get_provider` по сути не нужен.

```
$service_provider = resolve($service_type);
```

В результате мы удалили лишний класс. Но к сожалению остаётся проблема, что будет вызван exception если тип такой не найден.

Тут есть несколько путей.

1. Сделать просто try-catch и самому решать что делать с ошибкой.
2. Если ключ летит с фронта. Проверять есть ли такая константа прям в валидаторе или реквесте (не знаю что там у вас) и всё в контроллере уже не придётся обрабатывать.
3. Вариант сделать таблицу в бд с вашими сервисами и их привязками. Где колонки будут `abstract`, `concrete`, где `abstract`  будет `primary key` и при передаче в `resolve`  делать так (метод find возвращает null если не найдет):

   ```
   resolve(Service::find($service_type)) // Service это название модели нашей таблицы
   ```

тогда в провайдере при регистрации можно делать так:

```
Service::all()->each(function($service) {
    $this->app->bind($service->abstract, $service->concrete);
});
```

**UPD**

Если использовать бд, то есть способ связанный с `model bindings` чтобы не писать постоянно `find`

В маршруте делаем так:

```
Route::get('/test/{service}', [MyController::class, 'index'])...;
```

В результате в методе можно сразу получить наш класс.

```
public function index(Request $request, Service $service)
{
    $service_provider = resolve($service->abstract);
}
```